# Getting Operation Timed out when connecting Remote Database using SSH Private Key

Tags: jdbc, ssh, ssh-keys

I am trying to connect to a remote database using SSH Private Key, I am getting Operation Timed out error.

Not able to find out the reason.

***Code:***

```
package com.package.draft;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class RemoteConnectionOverSSH {

@SuppressWarnings("null")
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

    int lPort = 1111;
    int rPort = 2000;
    String lHost = "100.20.20.1";
    String rHost = "15.15.15.21";
    String user = "sshUserName";
    String dbUserName = "MySQLDBUserName";
    String dbPassword = "MySQLDBPassword";
    String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + lHost + ":" + lPort + "/db_test";

    Connection conn = null;
    Session session = null;
    try{
        java.util.Properties sqlConfig = new java.util.Properties();
        sqlConfig.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        System.out.println(sqlConfig.getProperty("StrictHostKeyChecking"));
        final JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session = jsch.getSession(user, rHost, 22);
        session.setConfig(sqlConfig);
        jsch.addIdentity("/Users/TestUser/.ssh/private.key");
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected");
        int assignedPort = session.setPortForwardingL(lPort, rHost, rPort);
        System.out.println("localhost:"+assignedPort+" -> "+rHost+":"+rPort);
        System.out.println("Port Forwarded");

        Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, dbUserName, dbPassword);
        System.out.println("Database Connection Established");
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if(conn != null && !conn.isClosed()){
            System.out.println("Closing Database Connection");
            conn.close();
        }
        if(session != null && session.isConnected()){
            System.out.println("Closing SSH Connection");
            session.disconnect();
        }
    }

  }
}
```

I've used my private key to connect to SSH.

***Exception Trace***

```
 com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:349)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:215)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at   com.package.draft.RemoteConnectionOverSSH.main(RemoteConnectionOverSSH.java:36)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:343)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Are you able to connect using a GUI SSH client to the same host from the same machine?

Comment: how would i do that? I am using SequelPro client and using same credentials I am able to connect to the database.

Comment: If it's a Linux machine, just use `ssh host`. If it's a Windows machine, use any GUI client of your choice (e.g. [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/)).

Comment: I am able to connect to the linux machine using below command:

`ssh sshUserName@host -p Port -i <path to privatekey>`

Comment: Is the `host` the same as `rHost = "15.15.15.21"` and `Port` is `22`?

Comment: host is same as rHost but port is not 22 its something else you can say rPort mentioned in the code.

Comment: OK, so it's not the same test. Either you need to test connection to port `22`, as you are doing in the code. Or connect to port `2000` in the code. You didn't explain us what the port is and `2000` is not a standard port, so it's difficult to help you.

Comment: yeah now I am able to connect to my remote machine using the correct port and the statement upto Port Forwarded is getting printed. Now the code is stuck in making mysql connection. `Communication Link failure exception`

Comment: now I am able to get the data.. thanks a lot @MartinPrikryl

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer or delete your question.